# Tell Apache to always serve index.php, no matter what is in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have written a frontend  [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) in Javascript. It uses Ember with its routing, fake URL, authentication and all the amazing stuff Ember handles almost implicitly.

The backend is written in PHP and the page shall be served by an Apache server.

Now, the page works just fine if the request is sent to the root file (aka index) and everything is handled from here. If I however reload the page at let's say `localhost/login`, Apache tries to find a file named login, which, naturally, doesn't exist, as everything is handled in Javascript and I get the widely-known 404 - `The requested URL /login was not found on this server.`

**How do I tell Apache to always serve `index.php`, no matter what is in the URL?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should look something like the default .htaccess for Laravel, which will always serve everything through the `/index.php` page without the actual `/index.php` in  the url ex `/index.php/login` will be just `/login`, but it's worth noting that this will not force it through the `/index.php` page if the file exists.

```
# Checks if the rewrite mod is on.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Force everything through the index.php file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```